# Getting the wrong window back from df.rolling

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I'm converting a series of data from 1 minute intervals to 5 minute intervals. To do this I am using the rolling and sum funcitons from pandas then attempting to slice in steps of 5. This makes sense to me, sum everything up, then take the rows that have the information I want, which is every 5th row.

However my code is not slicing how I intended and is instead ignoring row 0 for the operations. In the attached picture the Left column is the sliced code and the right column is the unsliced code. As the [Picture of Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YA0m.png) shows, the first slice happens at row 5 instead of 4 (the 5th data entry). I am geting the right length back in my slice, but clearly not getting all of the data I need. My code is below with tmpL on the Left and tmpR on the right. I am expecting to get rows 4 and 9 back instead of rows 5 and 10. What is the proper notation I should be using?

```
tmpL = df.rolling(window=5).sum()[::5]
tmpR = df.rolling(window=5).sum()
```

Comment: `[::5]` means take elements `[0]`, `[5]`, `[10]`... To take `[4]`, `[9]` ... you can use `[4::5]`.

Comment: This was really helpful for how I understand Slices, but I don't know how to mark this as solved due to how you answered.

Answer (score 0):

If this was me I would take the following approach:

```
tmp_df = df.rolling(window=5).sum()
df_5 = tmp_df[(tmp_df.index % 5) == 4]
```

`df_5` will be your desired output